# how to calculate Ethereum's practical maximum network size?

Tags: go-ethereum

What is the largest network size that Ethereum can achieve?
Lets say , the network latency is 50 milliseconds, how many nodes would the network allow to do not surpass the block time of 14 seconds?

If I assume that the network is connected serially then with 50ms latency i can transfer 20 messages in one second. In 14 seconds I can pass 280 messages serially. But Ethereum uses Kademlia protocol, which is like binary search.

Current Ethereum's network has about 100k nodes. With binary search they would have to use 21 time intervals of 50 milliseconds to distribute the block among the whole network.  (I divided 100k by 2 until I got to 1, result is 21) So, the latency to transmit 1 block among network should be theorically of 21*50ms=1 second.

But this is theory. In practice, what is the maximum limitations of Ethereum's network size?